# converting 0V - 10V to -5V - 5V

Tags: voltage, conversion, negative

i am an absolute novice when it comes to electronics. i am looking for an (ideally passive) circuit of some sort, that converts voltages from 0V - 10V to -5V to 5V.

i'd be gracious for any hint or places to read up on this. the conversion is for the purpose of a modular synthesizer and therefore needs to be rather precise (e.g. former 4V needs to be exactly -1V and so on).

Comment: If DC doesn't need to be transmitted (for example a sound signal), simple capacity coupling will do.

Comment: thank you very much @Bregalad. this sounds incredible! i suppose i don't need to transmit a sound signal – it's only control voltage i'd like to convert... any tip on how to do it?

Comment: benniy:  You need to supply more information.  What is the present source of the 0 - 10 volts? Batteries, AC converter, etc. What is the current consumption of the load ("modular synthesizer")? Often a conversion like this is a simple transposition of the DC common - the 0 volt reference point. I.e. where you "ground" the circuit.  Also, describe the nature of the load circuitry. Is it a module, a discrete circuit, an IC, etc.?

Comment: thanks @FiddyOhm – i'm sorry, i really know barely anything about these things.. the modular synth in general has a powered busboard that supplies it with -12V, +12V and 5V. it comes from a normal power supply / block / plug. does that make any sense at all?

Comment: the voltages that flow within the synth (so called "control voltage") are usually within a range of -5V to +5V. this is also the standard for playing notes. 0V is a C0, +1V is a C1 (an octave up) and so on... therefore, -1V would be a C-1

Comment: benniy: The problem with not knowing much about a subject is that you don't know what questions to ask. Can you provide a part # for the modular synthesizer, a schematic of your application, or some other illustration of how this voltage needs to be applied to your circuit or module?

Comment: @benniy No, you understood my comment backwards. What I meant is that if you're transfering a sound signal, simple capacitor coupling will do. However if the voltage stops to change then it won't work anymore as the coupling capacitor will discharge and gradually reset to 0 (high pass filter).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your control voltage is not (necessarily) varying much, such as when it commands a constant frequency or level, then there is no passive circuit which will do what you want. Instead, you'll need an op amp and some resistors. This circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzFBb4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

will do the job.

Fortunately, you have all 3 voltages available.

Accuracy will depend on 2 things: the accuracy of your 5 volts, and the accuracy of the resistors.

Resistors first. If you use readily available 1% resistors, the output will be accurate to about 1%. If you need better accuracy, you'll need more precise (and more expensive) resistors, but 0.1% resistors are fairly cheap and should be more than adequate for synthesizer work.

Now the 5 volts. The circuit is called a differential amplifier, and the level shift produced by the 5 volts is, obviously, equal to the value of the 5 volt input. If your system actually provides 4.9 volts, this is what you'll get for a shift.

For this application you'll want an older op amp such as the specified TL081. Be aware that many newer op amps are not rated for the voltages you're using, so be careful. Before you get an op amp, check the data sheet to make sure that it will work with +/- 12 volt supplies.

Comment: this is so incredible! really don't know how to thank you for your effort! ... i'll do some building asap :)